# Exception when downloading XML file from Internet on Android 4 (but it works on Android 2.3)

Tags: android, http-post, httpclient, android-xml, android-internet

I have a problem with downloading XML file from Internet in Android. I wrote some code and it works on Android 2.3 emulator. However, it doesn't work on Android 4.03 emulator and it doesn't work on real Android 4 device either.
Here is my code:

```
public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
    String xml = null;

    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // return XML
    return xml;
}
```

I have error on line:

```
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

Here is log from LogCat:

```
08-15 16:59:32.436: E/AndroidRuntime(623): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-15 16:59:32.436: E/AndroidRuntime(623): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testy/com.example.testy.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
08-15 16:59:32.436: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
08-15 16:59:32.436: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
08-15 16:59:32.436: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
08-15 16:59:32.436: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
08-15 16:59:32.436: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-15 16:59:32.436: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-15 16:59:32.436: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
08-15 16:59:32.436: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-15 16:59:32.436: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-15 16:59:32.436: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
08-15 16:59:32.436: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
08-15 16:59:32.436: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-15 16:59:32.436: E/AndroidRuntime(623): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
08-15 16:59:32.436: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099)
08-15 16:59:32.436: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:391)
08-15 16:59:32.436: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:242)
08-15 16:59:32.436: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:220)
08-15 16:59:32.436: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
08-15 16:59:32.436: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
08-15 16:59:32.436: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
08-15 16:59:32.436: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
08-15 16:59:32.436: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
08-15 16:59:32.436: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
08-15 16:59:32.436: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
08-15 16:59:32.436: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at com.example.testy.XMLParser.getXmlFromUrl(XMLParser.java:54)
08-15 16:59:32.436: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at com.example.testy.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:34)
08-15 16:59:32.436: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
08-15 16:59:32.436: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
08-15 16:59:32.436: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
08-15 16:59:32.436: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  ... 11 more
```

What can I do with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're performing a (potentially slow) network operation on the main thread. If your target SDK is 11 (Honeycomb) or higher this will throw a `NetworkOnMainThreadException` on Honeycomb or above, because this behaviour can block the UI and lead to an unresponsive app.  Even on pre-Honeycomb devices [this behaviour is discouraged](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/responsiveness.html).

You could use an `AsyncTask` to get around this, loading the data in its `doInBackground(..)`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using network feature on the main thread. You need to use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to accomplish this. 
Starting from Honeycomb [Strictmode](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2010/12/new-gingerbread-api-strictmode.html) checking is enabled by default. So Network operations raise an exception. Strictmode was not enabled in Gingerbread. Hence it is working in gingerbread but not in ICS